# Creating a JComboBox after setVisible makes JButton disappear

Tags: java, swing

While creating a JFrame and adding some components I noticed that if I create a instance of a JComboBox between setting the JFrame visible and adding a button, the button disappears.

I start of by creating a JFrame:

```java
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(200, 200);
```

Then I add set the frame visible and add a JButton:

```java
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.add(new JButton("text"));
```

It works as expected and displays one big button:

[image: JFrame with a button]

**BUT**, if I create one instance of a JComboBox in between those lines:

```java
frame.setVisible(true);
new JComboBox();
frame.add(new JButton("text"));
```

And now the buttons is gone..

[image: JFrame without a button]

I expect no change at all, since I'm only creating a instance and not assigning it to anything.
 **Why does the button disappears?**

Also, if move `new JComboBox();` above `frame.setVisible(true);`, the button goes visible again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you display the UI, it should not be modified from any thread except of the EDT. In the first case you had some "luck", and it worked. In the second case probably the time of creation of the JComboBox was long enough to prevent you from modifying the UI from a thread that is not the EDT.

What you should do, is invoking that code on the EDT:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.add(new JButton("text"));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that problem is in `setSize();` and `setVisible(true);` methods you are calling before adding components on your `JFrame`. So answer is simple, call `setSize();` and `setVisible(true)` in the end of code(or even better, call `pack();` instead of `setSize()`) and everything should work fine:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Fnatte {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        new JComboBox();
        frame.add(new JButton("Text"));
        //frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc for the add() method:

```
If the container has already been
displayed, the hierarchy must be 
validated thereafter in order to
display the added component.
```

Change:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
new JComboBox();
frame.add(new JButton("text"));
```

To:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
new JComboBox();
frame.add(new JButton("text"));
frame.validate();
```

I think the oddity you encountered is not so much the adition of "new JComboBox();"
but the fact that calling "frame.add(new JButton("text"));" after calling 
"frame.setVisible(true);" worked without calling "frame.validate();".